# Webdriver: Automation of Google Alerts options

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Here's the image of the options in Google Alerts:

[image]

I am trying to automate those dropdowns, but can't. Tried:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("document.getElementById(':3').innerHTML = 'As-it-happens';");
```

but it still accepts old selection when `Create Alert` clicked.

Also tried dropdown of `Select` in webdriver, but can't, because it is `div`, not `select`.

How can I make it select the correct one I need? Please visit here: https://www.google.com/alerts#

This step worked, but not able to select from the list:

```
WebElement howOften = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#create-alert-options > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(2) > div"));
howOften.click();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id for "As-it-happens" selection is actually ":0" :

```
WebElement as_it_happens = driver.findElement(By.id(":0"));
as_it_happens.click(); //make sure it's visible first
```

In case you wanted to select other options as well, you can view its page source (Ctrl+U) then search (Ctrl+F) the option's text.